# How to get route url from another component

Tags: angular

I would like to access to the route url from a different component `(header.component.ts)` than the one the route belongs to.

When I use `ActivatedRoute` or Route classes, I only see home page `'/'` and it doesn't get updated when I moved to different routes. I can only achieve this via window.location and ``` ngDoCheck()`` lifecycle ``` hook, but I would like to learn angular's own solution.

`header.component.ts`

```
ngDoCheck() {
    console.log(window.location.pathname)
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/Location#path, https://angular.io/api/router/Router#url,